# Typescript: conditional generic type base on optional property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

currently I have the following code in my React/Typescript app -

```ts
export type GetPricingParams = {
    search_id: number,
    promo_code?: string,
};
export type GetPricingData = {
    amount: number,
    currency: string,
    search_id: number,
    applied_promocode?: {
        type: 'AMOUNT' | 'PERCENT',
        discount: number,
    },
};
export const getPricing = api.post<GetPricingData, GetPricingParams>('/api/v1/pricing');
```

`api.post` method is a wrapper under axios post method -

```ts
post: <D = unknown, P = undefined>(uri: string): ReturnType<D, P> => (params, config) =>
{
    return axios.post(uri, params, config).then(r => Promise.resolve(r.data));
},
```

I'd like to specify `applied_promocode` as required parameter in `GetPricingData` if `promo_code` parameter has been specified in `GetPricingParams`.
I tried the following variant, but unfortunately it doesn't work -

```tsx
export type GetPricingParams = {
    search_id: number,
    promo_code?: string,
};
export type GetPricingDataCommon = {
    amount: number,
    currency: string,
    search_id: number,
};
export type GetPricingDataWithPromocode = GetPricingDataCommon & {
    applied_promocode: {
        type: 'AMOUNT' | 'PERCENT',
        discount: number,
    },
};
export const getPricing = <P extends GetPricingParams>(params: P) =>
{
    return api.post<
        P extends {promo_code: string} ? GetPricingDataWithPromocode : GetPricingData, 
        GetPricingParams
    >('/api/v1/pricing')(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close, you basically just needed to specify `GetPricingDataCommon` as the second part of your conditional.

Here's code that works (I removed the actual API call part as its not critical to the typing issue):

```js
export type GetPricingParams = {
  search_id: number
  promo_code?: string
}
export type GetPricingDataCommon = {
  amount: number
  currency: string
  search_id: number
}
export type GetPricingDataWithPromocode = GetPricingDataCommon & {
  applied_promocode: {
    type: "AMOUNT" | "PERCENT"
    discount: number
  }
}
export const getPricing = <P extends GetPricingParams>(params: P) => {
  return (
    data: P extends { promo_code: string }
      ? GetPricingDataWithPromocode
      : GetPricingDataCommon
  ) => {}
}

getPricing({ search_id: 2 })({ amount: 3, currency: "dollar", search_id: 7 })

// error as expected
getPricing({ search_id: 2, promo_code: "promo" })({
  amount: 3,
  currency: "dollar",
  search_id: 7
})

getPricing({ search_id: 2, promo_code: "promo" })({
  amount: 3,
  currency: "dollar",
  search_id: 7,
  applied_promocode: {
    type: "AMOUNT",
    discount: 50
  }
})
```

In a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwYAUoEsDGuAdgOZYCGU5AtgM5wC8cA3gFBxy3CX4AWA%20rgAmALjhEArtQBGwKOzhgoEahH74IQ4AH4xtGHlKsAvq1CRYCZKgzY8hUgBFyMcgGEVqooxYKaECSIYMUkZOQV8CSgoYCJ8RD0DYhIFLh4BYRCpWXlTc2h4JBR0TBwCZOdXAHVcGF4cFQgNLR9bMocSSvdPCG8AMl8OcjAwABtcYCF%20JUbm4DE2Dg4i%20bgAIgBBAFkAeQBVADkAFTW4AB91rABRACU3K%20O1hQ4hXFoNQODxbPCOUzzwAU4BoiPo4CRSvZkj4ADxYOCgGCxIT0NpQ0gUKh0AB8AAowJQaLQxFgAJSMbGDOAxGBRby455wIQucgkhEgJFEFEsRTKVTqTSrfSGEhwUxLJbaEp2cpOFk1OoNVRzRkcMRo2WdFkeaheBTkhiU5j-VisCEyjq45icbhQPiCURwABMYtJVrg-k%20YgAzAAaYFRGJxBLrIQQUajShrf1pO0ZR0AdldpoA9CmEdFoB76OZgPgkUIzZDNe7Y-bMs7-TN%20XMxGtqxBTsY3YsPaovXA-RFA7F4nWwxGo77Urby4mTKTTeb2slS6P42InVW%20Wpa%20sG02W3520EfcOOJFor2Q2sB5GoNGR%20kHWIE-uPSNxpNpiu163ltY69t9o97y83h8u5wAArAADAo-ykkAA).

If there's an issue I'm missing, please clarify.